# How can I setup my environment to use h2 for tests and mysql for development?

Tags: database, maven, spring-data, h2, jhipster

I'm using the default configuration for the `yo jhipster` generator except that I'm using mysql as my "dev" database. When I run `mvn test` my tests succeed with no failures.

However, I found that if I ran tests a second time, the suite would fail since it would run against the "dev" database...that wasn't 'rolled back' or 'reset' after the previous test run. I would rather have expected it to run against an in-memory h2 database as configured in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` that would be reset after each run.

How can I setup my environment with h2 for tests and mysql for development?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to solve this but I was able to get my tests to pass on repeated runs by creating a new profile "test".

I then had to do 2 things:

1) change `spring.profile` in src/test/resources/config/application.yml to "test" instead of "dev" (to make the test application.yml different from the dev one)

2) use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` instead of `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` in my tests

The test application.yml uses an h2 database and is reset between runs as desired.

Note: I also had some success with successive test runs without creating a new profile by annotating my test classes with:

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
```

as...

> At the end of the test the transaction will be rolled back and the data discarded leaving a fresh environment for the next test to execute.

see https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3/