# Different database for tests and development profile

Tags: jhipster

I'm thinking would be a good approach to have a database in memory (H2 for example) only for tests.
Development and Production profiles I think should use the same database (mysql, postgresql, mongoDB or whatever).

With this approach, tests can be executed without modify the database used on development, and it would be faster than executed on a no-memory database.

To use the same engine database for production and development profiles could prevent bugs due to different implementations of a same specification.

What do you think?

Comment: If someone wants to try it, I commited here https://github.com/ilopezluna/japan-at-home/commit/b5c6834c46fdf639017631e87b14311001396ac3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup my environment to use h2 for tests and mysql for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168293/how-can-i-setup-my-environment-to-use-h2-for-tests-and-mysql-for-development)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to a question I was wondering about a few months back. Does this answer help with what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170862/1098564

Comment: Yes, I think we have used the same approach, (take a look at commit mentioned on my comment before). Thanks!